# if statement updates variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
var text = 'abc';
if(text = '' || text != '')
    console.log(text);
else
    console.log('in else');
```

It is just a useless code snippet, but it gives the strange result which I was not expecting at all. So my curiosity brought me here.

It prints `true` only.

Why does it updates the `text` value to `true` rather than setting it as empty?

Comment: @Tushar I know, I am not checking the condition. I am updating the var

Comment: `text = ''` assignment, `text == ''` comparison, `text === ''` what you probably want

Comment: Perhaps the OP want it evaluated as `if ((text = '') || text != '')..`

Comment: What ever it should be, I am not achieving anything by this code I was just curious about the results :)

Comment: @Shaharyar, FYI, [js operator priority table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The expression

```
text = '' || text != ''
```

is parsed as

```
text = ('' || text != '')
```

The value of

```
('' || text != '')
```

is the boolean value `true` because `text != ''` is `true`.

Comment: damn priorities of operators :-D

Comment: Oh my God ! How you came to know? Ever experienced it before?

Comment: @Shaharyar well it's just how the language works :)  The assignment operator has fairly low precedence because, well, lots of things would be even more confusing.

Comment: But when I put something inside like `text = '2'`, it assigns the value, could you please elaborate this?

Comment: The `||` takes the first "truthy" value. The empty string is *not* truthy, but `2` is.  Thus the `||` result is the value of the left side, not the right side.

Answer (score 2):

The condition `'' || text != ''` is evaluated to `true`. and this value is then assigned to the variable `text`.

Here, `''` is false value, so the next condition after `||`(OR) is executed. As value of `text` is not empty string, the condition `text != ''` returns true and this value is assigned to `text`.